# Sesame Street project

Tags: objective-c, ios, quiz

I started a tutorial online to get a little bit more knowledge about views. But after I did the basic I decided to finish the game.

The game is a little "I spy" game where the user tries to guess the item loaded in a picture on the screen. They are been helped with some hints showed at the bottom. The user has 3 tries to guess the character, in this case a **Sesame Street character**.

[image]

What I am trying to have is the code reviewed:

- Style
- Best practices
- Model View Controller (MVC) best practices
- Language (objective C) specifics

  - Class cohesion and coupling

[This is the link to the project](http://www.filedropper.com/sesame).

This is the code for some of the key classes:

**Character.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class UIBezierPath;

/**
 * The Character object is the one used to store the imformation related to the
 * character in the game.
 */
@interface Character : NSObject

/**
 *  Name of the character
 */
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;

/**
 *  Points (doubles) associated with what enclosed the area of a character in the game
 */
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *points;

/**
 *  Url to the information for the character on the web
 */
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *url;

/**
 *  Set of hints that allow the player to identify a character
 */
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *hints;

/**
 *  Path associated with the coordinates (x, y) that define the path for the character
 */
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBezierPath *path;

- (instancetype) initWithName: (NSString *) name
               andCoordinates: (NSArray *) coordinates
                     andHints:(NSArray *) hints
                       andUrl: (NSString *)url;
- (BOOL) containsPoint: (CGPoint) point;
- (NSString *) printHints;
@end
```

**Character.m**

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Character.h"

@interface Character ()

@end

@implementation Character

/**
 *  Creates an instance of a character
 *
 *  @param name        name of the character
 *  @param coordinates coordinates that define a character space
 *  @param hints       hints for the users
 *  @param url         url to the character online
 *
 *  @return an instance of a Character
 */
- (instancetype) initWithName: (NSString *) name
               andCoordinates: (NSArray *) coordinates
                     andHints:(NSArray *) hints
                       andUrl: (NSString *)url {

    self = [super init];

    if (self) {

        // Public variables
        self.name = name;
        self.points = [self coordinatesToPoints:coordinates];
        self.hints = hints;
        self.url = url;

        //Set the private path.
        [self setPath];
    }

    return self;
}


/**
 *  Creates a UIBezierPath associated to an interanal class varible that defines
 *  the path/area for the character
 */
- (void) setPath {

    self.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    // Add the fist point.
    CGPoint point =  [[self.points firstObject] CGPointValue];
    [self.path moveToPoint: point];


    // Draw lines using all the points.
    for (id point in self.points) {
        [self.path addLineToPoint: [point CGPointValue]];
    }

    //Close the path at the end.
    [self.path closePath];

}

/**
 *  Translates from an array of doubles organized as x0, y0, x1, y1,...xn, yn
 *  into an array of CGpoints.
 *
 *  @param coordinates the array of coordinates
 *
 *  @return the array of points
 */
- (NSArray *) coordinatesToPoints: (NSArray *) coordinates {

    // Create the array of points
    NSMutableArray *points = [NSMutableArray array];
    CGFloat x = 0.0f;
    CGFloat y = 0.0f;

    for (int i = 0; i < [coordinates count]; i++) {

        if (i % 2) {
            //odd
            y = [[coordinates objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
            CGPoint point = CGPointMake(x, y);
            [points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];

        } else {
            //even
            x = [[coordinates objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
        }
    }

    return points ;
}


/**
 *  Check if a point is contained in the character path
 *
 *  @param point the point to check
 *
 *  @return True if point is contained, otherwise faulse
 */
- (BOOL) containsPoint: (CGPoint) point {

    return [self.path containsPoint:point];
}

/**
 *  Prints the array of hints into a format defined by bullets and new lines
 *
 *  @return the formatted result
 */
- (NSString *) printHints {

    static const NSString *BULLET = @"-";
    static const NSString *NEW_LINE = @"\n";

    NSString *result;
    NSString *line;


    for (NSString *hint in self.hints) {

        line = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", BULLET, hint];

        if (result) {
            result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", result, NEW_LINE, line];
        } else {
            result = line;
        }

    }

    return result;
}
@end
```

**Characters.h**

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

/**
 *  Characters is just a collection of Character. Acts as a 
 *  mediator between the objects and the JSON file
 */
@interface Characters : CAShapeLayer

/**
 *  NSArrayContaining the characters
 */
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *characters;

-(instancetype) initWithJSONfromURL: (NSString *) url;

@end
```

**Characters.m**

```
#import "Characters.h"
#import "Character.h"

@implementation Characters

/**
 *  Default initializer for the object Characters
 *
 *  @param urlString The Url where the properies JSON file is located.
 *
 *  @return An iharacters object
 */
-(instancetype) initWithJSONfromURL: (NSString *) urlString {

    self = [super init];


    if (self) {

        NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:urlString];
        NSError *error;
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                  options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                    error:&error];

        //Initialize the array
        self.characters = [NSMutableArray array];

        if (json && !error) {
            NSArray *items = [json objectForKey:@"characters"];

            for (NSDictionary *item in items) {

                NSArray *coordinatesString = [item objectForKey:@"coordinates"];
                NSMutableArray *coordinates = [NSMutableArray array];


                //Convert strings to doubles to doubles.
                for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < coordinatesString.count; i++) {
                    [coordinates addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[coordinatesString[i] doubleValue]]];
                }

                //Create a new character.
                Character *c = [[Character alloc] initWithName:[item objectForKey:@"name"]
                                                andCoordinates:coordinates
                                                      andHints:[item objectForKey:@"hints"]
                                                        andUrl:[item objectForKey:@"url"]];
                // Add it to the array
                [self.characters addObject:c];
            }
        }
    }
    return self;

}
@end
```

**TargetView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Character;

/**
 *  This is the object where all the action is going to happen. 
 *  It's a UIView kind of object that sits right above the charactes image.
 */
@interface TargetView : UIView

/**
 *  The character that's selected at the moment
 */
@property (nonatomic, strong) Character *character;

/**
 *  The chape for the crosshair target
 */
@property (nonatomic, strong) CAShapeLayer *crosshairLayer;

@end
```

**TargetView,m**

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "TargetView.h"
#import "Characters.h"
#import "Character.h"


/**
 *  Maximum zixe for the crosshair circle
 */
static const CGFloat CROSSHAIRS_CIRCLE_SIZE = 20.0;
/**
 *  Maximum size for the crosshair
 */
static const CGFloat CROSSHAIRS_SIZE = 30.0;
/**
 *  Maximum size for the crosshair inset
 */
static const CGFloat CROSSHAIRS_CIRCLE_INSET = (CROSSHAIRS_SIZE - CROSSHAIRS_CIRCLE_SIZE) / 2;


@implementation TargetView

#pragma mark - Initializers

/**
 *  Default initializer for the Targetview
 *
 *  @param frame The CGRect for the view
 *
 *  @return An instance of the TargetView
 */
-(instancetype) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {

        // Create the shape layer.
        self.crosshairLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];

        // Set it to transparent so we can still see the image behind.
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        // CAShape properties are set here, drawing must be done is drawRect.
        self.crosshairLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, CROSSHAIRS_SIZE, CROSSHAIRS_SIZE);
        self.crosshairLayer.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2.0, self.frame.size.height / 2.0);


        self.crosshairLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
        self.crosshairLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
        self.crosshairLayer.lineWidth = 2.0;

        [self.layer addSublayer:self.crosshairLayer];

    }
    return self;
}


#pragma mark - Drawing

/**
 *  Method to draw on the screen
 *
 *  @param rect The GCRect to draw on
 */
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    //Draw the circle.
    CGRect circlePathBox = CGRectInset(self.crosshairLayer.bounds, CROSSHAIRS_CIRCLE_INSET, CROSSHAIRS_CIRCLE_INSET);
    UIBezierPath *circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:circlePathBox];

    //Draw vertical.
    CGPoint drawPoint = CGPointMake(self.crosshairLayer.bounds.size.width / 2.0, 0.0);
    [circlePath moveToPoint:drawPoint];
    drawPoint.y = self.crosshairLayer.bounds.size.height;
    [circlePath addLineToPoint:drawPoint];


    //Draw horizontal.
    drawPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, self.crosshairLayer.bounds.size.height / 2.0);
    [circlePath moveToPoint:drawPoint];
    drawPoint.x = self.crosshairLayer.bounds.size.width;
    [circlePath addLineToPoint:drawPoint];


    //Add the path to the layer.
    self.crosshairLayer.path = [circlePath CGPath];

}


#pragma mark - Events

/**
 *  Event handler controller for the view
 *
 *  @param touches Set of touches on the screen.
 *  @param event   The event
 */
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(nullable UIEvent *)event; {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if (touch) {
        CGPoint crosshairPos = [touch locationInView:self];

        self.crosshairLayer.position = crosshairPos;

        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
@end
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class TargetView;
@class Characters;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

/**
 *  The view that contains the characters
 */
@property (nonatomic, strong) TargetView * targetView;
/**
 *  The characters collection
 */
@property (nonatomic, strong) Characters *characters;

/**
 *  The image view where the characters are loaded
 */
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *riddleImageView;

/**
 *  The hints label for the active game
 */
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *hints;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TargetView.h"
#import "Characters.h"
#import "Character.h"


/**
 *  Maximum number of Strikes in the game
 */
static const int MAX_STRIKES = 3;

@interface ViewController ()

/**
 *  Keeps track of the number of strikes in the game.
 */
@property int strikes;

@end


@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImageView *imageView = [self riddleImageView];

    if (imageView) {
        // Start to create the view.
        CGRect targetViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);
        self.targetView = [[TargetView alloc] initWithFrame:targetViewFrame];
        self.targetView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        // Add the character to the view.
        self.characters = [[Characters alloc] initWithJSONfromURL:[self resolveUrl:@"characters"]];

        if (self.targetView) {
            [imageView addSubview: self.targetView];
        }
    }

    //Set a new game
    [self newGame];
}


/**
 *  Adds a random character to the TargetView object.
 */
- (void) addRandomCharacter {

    uint32_t maxCharacters = (uint32_t) [self.characters.characters count];
    NSUInteger randomIndex= arc4random_uniform(maxCharacters);
    Character *character = [self.characters.characters objectAtIndex:randomIndex];

    self.targetView.character  = character;

    NSLog(@"We randomly selected %@", self.targetView.character.name);

    // Update the view label
    self.hints.text = [character printHints];
}

/**
 *  Resolves the URL for the characters.json file to make sure we are using
 *  the correct full path.
 *
 *  @param url The original file name
 *
 *  @return Full Url for the file
 */
- (NSString *) resolveUrl: (NSString*) url {

    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString * urlString = [bundle pathForResource:url ofType:@"json"];

    return urlString;
}

/**
 *  Creates a new game
 */
- (void)newGame {

    // Reset the strikes
    self.strikes = 0;

    // Add the correct image. Add the image to the view.
    UIImageView *imageView = [self riddleImageView];

    if (imageView) {
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Seasame-St-Characters.png"];
        imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        // Get a new character
        [self addRandomCharacter];
    }
}

/**
 *  Action to create a new game.
 *
 *  @param sender Id for the item that sent the action
 */
- (IBAction)new:(id)sender {
    [self newGame];
}

/**
 *  Action to check the response for the game
 *
 *  @param sender Id for the item that sent the action
 */
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {

    //get the position
    TargetView *t = [self targetView];
    CGPoint p =  t.crosshairLayer.position;

    Character *c = t.character;

    if ([c containsPoint:p]) {
        NSLog(@"We got %@", c.name);

        self.hints.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You won! \n\n The character is: %@", c.name];

    } else {
        self.strikes++;
    }

    //Check for game over
    if (self.strikes >= MAX_STRIKES) {
        NSLog(@"Game Over");self.riddleImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Seasame-St-Characters-GameOver.png"];

    }
}
@end
```